# Creating sub-commands with the same name in Go w/ Cobra

Tags: go, command-line-interface, go-cobra

I'm very new to Go in general, and this is my first project in Cobra.

It seems easy enough to create commands in Cobra with the command-line tool:
`cobra add <command>`

And adding sub-commands seems easy enough as well.
`cobra add <subcommand> -p '<command>'`

Where I've run into an issue is having two sub-commands for two different commands, but having the sub-commands have the same name. For instance:

I may have a command named 'people' and a command named 'places'.
`cobra add people`
`cobra add places`

Each command needs its own sub-command called 'add'.
`cobra add add -p 'people'`
`cobra add add -p 'places'`

The second command will fail because it will attempt to create an 'add.go' file which was already created by the first command. Is it possible to add sub-commands of the same name to different parent commands? Where the end result would be something like:
`people add --first "bob" --last "smith"`
`places add "someplace" --zip "12345"`

Answer (score 2):

All `command add` does is generate a Go source file for you. You could write the file yourself; or you could take the first one that was created, rename it, then create the next one. You'll also likely have to rename some global variables/functions in the generated files to avoid name collisions.